# UnityEventSystem Cannot distinguish target component in event system on objects with multiple identical components

Tags: unity-game-engine, events, event-handling

I have the following [GameObject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYl8t.png) which has a bunch of components, One of which contains a Unity event system (IE_AllTriggerList) and 2 identical components (IE_BlinkyLights). I drag and drop this current object into the event system link, and then when I go to select which function to invoke (As seen in the picture) it only shows one instance of IE_BlinkyLights. Is there anyway I can be able to select specifically which target script without having to put each IE_BlinkyLights on different children objects, or have to make inherited children of it?

The items in this game heavily use event systems to ease the building of weapons. However there can be multiple numbers (1-5) of the same scripts on the same object, such as IE_BlinkyLights, IE_ParticleTriggers, etc.

Comment: Multiple components of the same type on an object generally don't play nice.

Comment: I had [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52409065/how-can-i-reference-multiple-components-of-the-same-type-in-a-button-in-unity3d). I think this happens because Unity internally uses something similar to `GetComponent` which always returns only the first match. I had to write a custom class to list all my components and than reference this list in the button/event instead .. it's at least a workaround. An alternative seems to be to have a child object for each component .. but this also seems a bit ugly

Comment: I read your link, not exactly sure how to implement that so it can support different kinds of IEs, such as IE_Blinky, IE_Projectile, IE_Particle, etc